# Routing Issue with Iron Router in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Im getting the "waiting on local host" in Chrome and Firefox but doubt there is an issue with browsers with my laptop; the issue is with Iron Router. See my router.js:

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',
  notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',
  waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('jobs'); }
});


Router.route('/', {name: 'jobsList'});


Router.route('/jobs/:_id/', {
  name: 'jobPage',
  data: function() { return Jobs.findOne(this.params._id); }
});

// route to edit a job post
Router.route('/jobs/:_id/edit/', {
  name: 'jobEdit',
  data: function() { return Jobs.findOne(this.params._id); }
});

Router.route('/jobs/create', {name: 'jobCreate'});

var requireLogin = function() {
  if (! Meteor.user()) {
    if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
      this.render(this.loadingTemplate);
    } else {
      this.render('accessDenied');
    }
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
}

Router.onBeforeAction('dataNotFound', {only: 'jobPage'});

Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin, {only: 'jobCreate'});
```

Going to `/jobs/sgjdhdbhbbd` the page does not load, but if I change `Router.route('/jobs/:_id/', {` to `Router.route('/:_id/', {`, the page loads. I am lost. Are there any tweaks to try?

********EDIT********

I am also using [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/) if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your support. I should have mentioned I was using Polymer in the first my so my apologies.

The issue is with Polymer as discussed [here](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1052). I have done what **ThaumRystra** said and all is well.

I have solved the issue by including a trailing forward slash on all polymer imports:

Replace:

```
rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-toast/paper-toast.html">
rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-fab/paper-fab.html">
```

With:

```
rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-toast/paper-toast.html">
rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-fab/paper-fab.html">
```

If you have an image src url, include the forward slash at the front and it will display.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from here:

```
Router.route('/jobs/create', {name: 'jobCreate'});
```

The "create" is used as "id" on your route 'jobCreate'

Just try something like this

```
Router.route('/jobs/view/:_id/', {
  name: 'jobPage',
  data: function() { return Jobs.findOne(this.params._id); }
});

// route to edit a job post
Router.route('/jobs/edit/:_id/', {
  name: 'jobEdit',
  data: function() { return Jobs.findOne(this.params._id); }
});

Router.route('/jobs/create/', {name: 'jobCreate'});
```

EDIT:

The source of problem is here:

```
Router.route('/jobs/:_id/', {
```

All path after /jobs/ is used as :id

Comment: No. Did not work; same issue. If I go to the page using pathFor and do a browser refresh, it lags. If I use: `<paper-fab icon="create" class="pink" onclick="location.href='{{pathFor 'jobCreate'}}'"></paper-fab>` it lags. Any link with `/jobs/` it lags

Comment: What is the publication "jobs"?

Comment: Do you have somethings like this in /server/: `Meteor.publish('jobs', function() { return Jobs.find({}); });` ?? If no, you have a problem :) if yes, can you paste it?

Comment: I have that exactly. Anything after "/" with (:_id) it hangs. eg: `/jkadhb/(:_id)`